# Using variables and functions in an object literal

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, object-literal, edit-in-place

I am trying to get the [ckeip](http://dave-earley.com/jquery/ckeditor-edit-in-place-jquery-plugin/) jquery plugin to parse the id of my textarea to my php file.

The plugin is activated by the class name of my textarea:

```
$('.ckeip_edit').ckeip({
```

And then data is passed to my php file with an object literal:

```
data: {
name1     : 'value1',
name2     : 'value2'
      },
```

**I need to use the id attribute of my textarea** in one of these so tried:

```
data: {
name   : 'value',
id     : function(){this.getAttribute("id")}
      },
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Can I use variables in an object literal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you want a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and use `this` where needed inside to get an attribute from the current element for usage, like this:

```
$('.ckeip_edit').each(function() {
  $(this).ckeip({
    data: {
      name : 'value',
      id : this.id
    },
    //options...
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been banging my head on the desk for ages trying to get this to work. This has solved my problem entirely. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because `this` refers to the `data` object. You need to save the jQuery object so you can use it inside the object later.

Try something like:

```
var textarea = $('.ckeip_edit');

textarea.ckeip({
  data: {
    name : 'value',
    id : textarea[0].id;
  }
});
```

Comment: `.getAttribute()` isn't a jQuery method :)  Also it would get the ID of the *first* one if it was, not of each as you are executing the plugin.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Oops, you're right. I had `textarea[0].id` but changed it to `getAttribute` for some dumb reason. Fixed.

Comment: Say there's 20 of these...it still gets the `id` of the first one only :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: He refers to the textarea as "my textarea" -- singlular, so I assume there is only one.